# How to differentiate multiple state change on useEffect hooks second argument?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Here my code :**

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(a change){ do something a}
  if(b change){ do something b}
}, [a,b])
```

How to differentiate when state change between a or b ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should focus a single `useEffect` per action:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do something a
}, [a])

useEffect(() => {
  // do something b
}, [b])
```

But for you question, [use `usePrevious`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) to compare it to previous value:

```
const aRef = usePrevious(a);

useEffect(() => {
  // Or use custom comparator compare(a,aRef.current)
  if (a !== aRef.current) {
    // a changed
    aRef.current = a;
  }
}, [a ,b])
```